# elementary OS 5.1 Hera tooltips messed up

Tags: plank, release-hera, user-interface

I'm having an issue with elementary OS. Note that I'm totally new to any kind of Linux OS :)

The tooltips on my dock look scrambled:

[image]

What can I do to correct this? Googling didn't help me, probably because I don't know what to search for..

Note: only some tooltips look like this, while others are fine

Comment: This problem is reported a few times already, I believe it is after the linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 updates a few days ago. I am affraid to update it because of that, but can you confirm if the popup problem is on a folders only - do you have it also into single apps? Also, do you have the same problem on the wingpanel(top bar of the os)  also?

Comment: The bug appears on folders, and on tabs in Epiphany. Also on certain system items like Multitask View and System Settings. I just recently did a fresh install/update so I guess I have the newest version of everything, including bugs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with the `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04` update of Jan 16 and radeon graphics cards.
There are newer versions of the package to download. More explained version of this answer in this [post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22090/something-wrong-with-my-panel-and-dock-popover).

Or download the newer packages in [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04/1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1/+build/18591330).

Comment: This solved my issue, many thanks!